# Centering in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode6

I am a little bit confused by Xcode 6 Storyboard.

The auto layout seems to be a very powerful tool to build UI for different devices. However, no matter what kinds of layout I chose (compact or any height/width) or even uncheck the "Use auto layout" and "Use size classes", what I mapped in the storyboard view always looks different when I am testing (using an iPhone 6).

For example if I left a UIButton at the center of the storyboard, it will be a little right down away from center when appears on my iPhone 6.

Could anyone please give me some help on this. Maybe just for iPhone6 instead of different devices. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you should have a look at [Auto Layout and Layout Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html).

Answer (score 10):

If you simply want to center an UI element check both `Horizontal Center in Container` and `Vertical Center in Container` in the storyboard constraints alignment popover.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it works for that single element. Is there any way to make a layout that shows what I will actually see in a real device?

Comment: They removed the word "Center" from those options in later XCode versions

Answer (score 0):

The reason, you are having this issue is the mis-matched stimulator size. For example, the apple standard for iPhone 6 is a frame of 400 x 600 pt, meaning 2:3. So,
First, turn on the auto Layout and size classes. Then change "wAny hAny" to "compact hAny".

[image]

If, you change the Stimulated Size now, you will se the width as 400 and height as 600.

[image]

After this you need to add the UIButton at the centre and even without adding any constrain, you will see your button to be centered in the frame.

Comment: Thank you. But I tried this and the UI Button is still a little bit away from the center when I run in simulator.

Comment: How about you add the centre horizontally and centre vertically constrain. It should give you a centred button in iPhone 6+ stimulator and yes it may fluctuate a little for iPhone 6. So, try adding the constrain now. you should be fine then.